# Работа с firebase . Вывод данных

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, firebase

[image: e]

Добрый день , подскажите пожалуйста , как вывести данные в таком порядке ,как показано на скрине .
Вот мой код (android / kotlin) :

```
 myRef = database.getReference(user.uid)
myRef.orderByChild("theme","desc").addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            // This method is called once with the initial value and again
            // whenever data at this location is updated.
            //dataList.clear()
            for (postSnapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
                Log.e(
                    "T@@@@AG",
                    postSnapshot.key.toString() + "  /" +
                    postSnapshot.child("theme").value.toString() + "  /" +
                            postSnapshot.child("message").value.toString()
                )}
```

Comment: А в чем логика такой сортировки?Используй order https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/database/Query и добавь поле по которому они будут сортироваться(время к примеру)

Comment: А в коде это как будет , а то не совсем понятно , спасибо